# Escrever múltiplos arquivos csv em Python

Tags: python, csv, multiple

Olá! Minha dúvida é a seguinte: escrevi um programa que, com as informações que eu inserir, ele vai coletar um número de links (esse número varia) e vai armazená-los em um csv. Depois, ele vai abrir cada um destes links e coletar alguns dados, salvando-os em outro csv. O problema é nessa segunda parte...

Quando usamos algo como " csvFile = open('Arquivo.csv', 'wt+') ", ele vai criar um arquivo chamado Arquivo.csv. A questão é que meu programa vai fazer isso várias vezes seguidas, e se eu mantiver o nome da forma como está ele não vai criar um Arquivo(1).csv (como o windows costuma fazer com arquivos de mesmo nome), ele vai substituir um arquivo em cima do outro. Se a quantidade de vezes que meu programa roda fosse pré-definida, eu poderia escrever opens quantas vezes precisassem, o problema é que não é, ele pode executar isso 10 vezes, ou 1000, etc...

Como posso fazer pra que meu programa crie um csv com os dados coletados, e no link seguinte ele crie um csv diferente, sem substituir o arquivo anterior? Tipo Arquivo 1.csv, Arquivo 2.csv, Arquivo 3.csv, etc. É possível isso?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Jordan, você pode tornar a pergunta um pouco mais clara? O que você já tentou fazer?  Qual é exatamente sua dúvida? Pergunto porque o [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) abre um arquivo para leitura/gravação, se você quiser abrir outro arquivo basta executar outro `open()` e gravar em outro arquivo.

Comment: Bom, quando usamos algo como " csvFile = open('Arquivo.csv', 'wt+') ", ele vai criar um arquivo chamado Arquivo.csv. A questão é que meu programa vai fazer isso várias vezes seguidas, e se eu mantiver o nome da forma como está ele não vai criar um Arquivo(1).csv (como o windows costuma fazer com arquivos de mesmo nome), ele vai substituir um arquivo em cima do outro. Se a quantidade de vezes que meu programa roda fosse pré-definida, eu poderia escrever opens quantas vezes precisassem, o problema é que não é, ele pode executar isso 10 vezes, ou 1000, etc...

Comment: Jordan, a maneira mais efetiva é você editar a pergunta com estes esclarecimentos. Dessa maneira é mais fácil de entender sua dúvida, sua pergunta volta ao topo das perguntas mais recentes e os votos para fechar sua pergunta temporariamente podem ser cancelados.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, atualizei lá.

Comment: Os nomes devem ser dinâmicos. Você pode usar da data e horário no nome do arquivo, você pode ter outro arquivo que guarde o último nome de arquivo criado, você também pode ler os arquivos da pasta pra descobrir qual é o último... existem várias abordagens. Você só precisa decidir qual te ajuda mais.
Assim que tiver um tempo formulo uma resposta aqui.

Comment: Acho que ainda não fui exatamente claro. Suponha que o programa execute 5 vezes. Ele não vai gerar 5 arquivos csv com o mesmo nome, e sim apenas 1, com os dados coletados da última execução.

Comment: A estrutura então seria, um arquivo principal com os links e um arquivo para cada link que tiver nesse arquivo principal?

Comment: Fernando, isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa função abaixo acha um nome único para o arquivo. Ela vai acrescentando `001`, `002` etc até encontrar um número que não exista ainda.

```
def acha_proximo_nome(nome_arquivo):
    if not os.path.exists(nome_arquivo):
        return nome_arquivo
    base, extensao = os.path.splitext(nome_arquivo)
    numero = 1
    while True:
        nome_arquivo = '{}_{:03d}{}'.format(base, numero, extensao)
        if not os.path.exists(nome_arquivo): 
            return nome_arquivo
        numero += 1
```

A forma de usar:

```
f = open(acha_proximo_nome('arquivo.csv'), 'w', newline='')
```

Comment: Nosklo, desculpa a demora. Muito obrigado! Eu pesquisei bastante sobre manipulação de csv, mas não achei nada que atendesse minha dúvida. Vou testar sua resposta e retorno aqui, mas já está ajudando demais!

Comment: Amigo, deu certinho aqui!! Ele criou o "arquivo.csv" e os seguintes eram arquivos diferentes, separados por número (001, 002, 003....). Era exatamente o que eu queria, muito obrigado!!